# ActionMailer works on localhost but doesn't in a public server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

I built an application with Rails 3 and I made a simple contact us page to send mail through my SMTP server.
The problem is my app can send mail when I run it in my local host (my pc), but it doesn't work when I run the app in the hosted server (hostgator).
The funny stuff is that the smtp server is the same!

This is the config in my localhost(and it works!):

**config/environments/developer.rb**

```
# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

**config/initializers/setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "mail.mydomain.org",  
  :port                 => 26,  
  :domain               => "app.mydomain.org",  
  :user_name            => "register@app.mydomain.org",  
  :password             => "********",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => false  
}
```

The url for my host server is app.mydomain.org, so in the hosted app I changed only this:

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.org' }
...
```

In the host server, just for now I run the app with WEBrick in development mode.
And I get a timeout error:

```
....
Timeout::Error (execution expired):
  app/controllers/contact_us_controller.rb:13:in `create'
...
```

Am I missing somenthing??

**EDIT & SOLVED:**

Hostgator support staff have just find out the cause of this issue.
In the `ActionMailer` setup, the `:address` has to be `localhost`, and not `mail.mydomain.org`. So the ActionMailer would be:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "localhost",  
  :port                 => 26,  
  :domain               => "app.mydomain.org",  
  :user_name            => "register@app.mydomain.org",  
  :password             => "********",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => false  
}
```

Comment: Maybe Hostgator blocks the SMTP port?

Comment: if it would be so, it wouldn't work when I run the app in my pc, isn't it?

Comment: hehe..I thought the same..and I just asked to HostGator support and they said port 25/26 isn't blocked :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean development.rb, not developer.rb. This setting only runs in development and assuming you've set RAILS_ENV as production on the server, it will be production.rb, not development.rb, is going to be processed.

If the server is the same on both, you could move this to application.rb (or a script in config/initializers). You might want a different setup for production though, so that it's pointing to localhost. That may also fix the problem here, in case there's some DNS issue or server config preventing the outgoing SMTP request.

Comment: Yes, I mean development.rb :) and in the hosted server I didn't set RAILS_ENV because I'm just running a showcase of the app.
The server is the same on both hosts, and it will be so for some months..